# Using metadata and/or reflection to generate ASP.NET tooltips?

Tags: c#, asp.net, reflection, tooltip, metadata

Using a C#/ASP.NET, I was wondering if there is a way to use metadata to easily generate tooltips for labels and textboxes.  I have found many resources on how to do this in ASP.NET MVC, but not plain ASP.NET.  I have tried using various `Display` attributes as well as `Description` with no success.  Is there a simple way to automate this?

For example, I want to use code such as below to display "Date that the application was sent" when the mouse is hovered over the `asp:Label` or `asp:TextBox` that corresponds to `DateSent` on the generated web page.

```
public class ProjectMetadata
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter a date")]
    [Description("Date that the application was sent")]
    public object DateSent { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter a description")]
    [StringLength(256, ErrorMessage="Description must be 256 characters or less")]
    public object Description { get; set; }
}

[MetadataType(typeof(ProjectMetadata))]
public partial class Project
{
    public DateTime DateSent { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

**EDIT**
Note that currently I am letting ASP.NET do all of the work generating the controls on the page (nothing done in code-behind):

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbDateSent" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DateSent", "{0:d}") %>'/>

<asp:Label ID="LabelDateSent" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DateSent", "{0:d}") %>'/>
```

Perhaps this is where I need to add something like: `ToolTip='<%# SomeExpressionHere %>'`?

Answer (score 0):

How are you populating your .NET controls? I'm guessing like this:

```
Project project = GetProject();

// TextboxProjectName is your TextBox on your Page / UserControl

TextboxProjectDescription.Text = project.Description; 
TextboxProjectDescription.Attributes["data-tooltip"] = project.DateSent.ToShortDateString(); // Or whatever format you want
```

Then you'll have this markup:

```
<input type="text" data-tooltip="Your date string" />
```

Then you can simply use a jQuery Tooltip library to tooltip all HTML elements where data("tooltip") is found.

**Edit**

Try this:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(ProjectMetadata))]
public partial class Project
{
    public DateTime DateSent { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string TooltipText 
    { 
       get {
           return "Date: " + DateSent.ToShortDateString(); // whatever tooltip you want
       }
       set {}
    }
}
```

Then you can do, as requested:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbDateSent" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DateSent", "{0:d}") %>'
ToolTip='<%# Bind("TooltipText") %>' />
```

Comment: Thanks for the response - though I was hoping to find something using just ASP.NET and not having to manually do it in code-behind (see EDIT above)

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect your needs.